# Regex to remove the first two characters of a string

Tags: regex

I want to remove the first two characters from a string using Regular expression. The string length is not fixed and can be any number of characters.

EX : FIELD 1 = FERNANDO --> REGEX --> Expected value in FIELD 2 should be
     FIELD 2 = RNANDO

Have tried this on destination field (?<=[.!?])\s[A-Z], but nothing happens once I enter the value in the source field.

Comment: Where are you using the regex?

Comment: What happens if the word only has 1 or 2 characters? For example `e` or `ex` - are they removed or left as they are?

Comment: Depending on your language, there might be features that already do that without regex (ex : python `s[2:]`). With regex, check that there is at least 2 characters, then replace `^..(.*)$` with group 1 in your string

Comment: the incoming message will have more than 2 characters. For ex. If the message is 2 digit ISO country code + Phone number, I just need the phone number and not the country code. US9829019 should result as 9829019

Comment: Try `(?<=^[A-Z][A-Z])\d+$` See https://regex101.com/r/e4e2qf/1

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a programming language here, then most likely you don't/should not need to even use regex.  Just take a substring, e.g. in Java:

```
String input = "FERNANDO";
String output = input.substring(2);  // same call for JavaScript
```

If you wanted to use a regex replacement approach, you could match the following:

```
^.{1,2}
```

and then replace with empty string, to remove the first one or two characters.  Or, for a pure regex approach, try matching on:

```
(?<=^..).*$
```

Comment: The fields on  tool I'm using only supports Regex. So I have to use regex only

Comment: If your regex tool supports lookbehinds (which your question seems to imply), you may try matching `(?<=^..).*$`